# Is this ternary or bitwise?

Tags: javascript

Can anyone please explain how this line works.

```
 a & 3 || (b, c)
```

Does the first part translate to:

```
 a = a & 3;
```

or is that a ternary code and if true b is returned, else c? thanks

Comment: that isn't the ternary operator.

Comment: How does an expression without any assignment suddenly turn into an assignment? Do you have a typo somewhere?

Comment: thats a messed up piece of code.

Comment: Is that a puzzle or a practical question ?

Comment: If a question is [closed](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13125086/understanding-ternary-operators/13125604#13125604) there's no point in asking it a second time, honestly. I gave you the links to the MDN pages on JS operators, the only _"effort"_ you had to put in was RTFM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

(Note on terminology: In `1 + 2`, 1 and 2 are "operands" and + is an "operator")

The first operator in that expression (`&`) is a bitwise 'and': https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Bitwise_Operators

The second operator (`||`) is a logical 'or', which returns the first operand if it's truthy (if it would pass an `if` check), and the second one otherwise.

The third one (`,`) is the comma operator, which simply returns the second operand.

So, in plain English: Take the bitwise 'and' of `a` with `3` (which is 11 in binary), meaning that the resulting value will be one of 0, 1, 2, or 3 depending on the value of the first two bits in `a`. If it is not zero, return that value. Otherwise, return `c`, but `b` will also be evaluated.

For example, if `a` is 2, then `a & 3` will be 10 & 11 == 10 (since 1 & 1 == 1 and 0 & 1 == 0), which is 2 and truthy (the only falsy number is 0 or 0.0), so that will be the return value of the whole expression, and `b` and `c` will not even be evaluated. On the other hand, if `a` is 4, then `a & 3` will be 100 & 11 == 000, which is falsy, so `(b, c)` will be evaluated and the result will be that `c` is the return value.

Answer (score 2):

I think the first part is doing a bitwise and with 3. If that's truthy, return that.

Otherwise, it will return `c` based on the comma operator.

```
if (a & 3 != false)
   return a & 3;
else
   return c;
```

Answer (score 2):

That is not a ternary operator. The way `a || b` works is that `a` is evaluated and if `a` coerces to `true` then `a` is returned, otherwise `b` is evaluated and returned. `&` is bitwise and. The second part of the expression is not very meaningful but I believe it will return the value of `c`.

So the meaning is: "if a bitwise and 3 is not 0 then return that, otherwise return c". It does behave a bit like the ternary operator in that sense... And `a` remains unchanged.

Answer (score 2):

If one of the last two bits of the binary writing of `a` is "1", this returns `a&3`.

In the opposite, `a & 3` is 0, so this returns `(b, c)`, which is `c`.

What it does seems clear but I can't imagine why...

If a is a positive integer, this could be written as

```
a%4||c
```

which clearly shows the periodic nature of the operation.

Comment: `a % 4` is not equivalent to `a & 3`, and `(b, c)` is different from `c` in that it evaluates `b` (in the case that evaluating `b` has side effects).

Comment: Evaluating a variable name does nothing.

Comment: Sorry, I was not really contradicting you, just making notes for posterity in case someone thinks this is a drop-in replacement. I meant the case where `a` is not a positive integer and `b` is replaced with an arbitrary expression.

Comment: @Kiyura OK. Regarding posterity, let's hope it won't be filled with such code. I can't see a reason to use this other than obfuscation. If somebody *really* (which I doubt) found it efficient, then he should only have typed it with an explanation in comment.